# c# runtime polymorphism with abstract base class

Tags: c#, object, polymorphism, runtime

I am trying to clean up an existing code base, and am having trouble with using a generic reference name to the different derived classes of an abstract class.

For instance:

```
public abstract class Base<T> : Utilities.CommonRequiredObject
{
    protected List<T> RawContents = new List<T>();
    .
    .

    public abstract void LoadContents(List<T> Contents);        // Each Class needs to load and process differently
    protected List<T> Contents;

    public virtual void DoSomething()           // Default here for common use. Defined in Each class for its specifics (if needed)
    {
    ...
    }
    public abstract List<T> FunctionToGetContents();

}

public class FOO : Base<string>
{
    public override void DoSomething() ...
    public override List<string> FunctionToGetContents() ...
}

public class BAR : Base<byte>
{
    public override void DoSomething() ...
    public override List<byte> FunctionToGetContents() ...
}
```

Main Logic to try to use common variable.  I want to create a new class to use, but want to use it then in a runtime polymorphic way. As the classes have the common functionality, and have overrides where needed, I want to be able to create an instance, and then use it:

```
IE: Base<T> ObjectToUse;
```

This way, I can simply refer to the `ObjectToUse` in the following code and call common methods.  As I inherited some common routines from another base class, I am not sure if I can use an interface or not.

```
if(variable)
{
    FOO ObjectToUse = new FOO();
}
else
{
    BAR ObjectToUse = new BAR();
}

ObjectToUse.LoadContents(ObjectToUse.FunctionToGetContents());
ObjectToUse.DoSomething();
...
```

Edit:
Based on the comments I received quickly (thanks again everyone) would it be better than to remove the Generic (`Base<T>`) and have the classes all of type Base(), then I could define the `ObjectToUse` simply as `Base ObjectToUse;` I believe.

Comment: This is not going to work. Your classes `Base<string>` and `Base<byte>` do not have a common ancestor.

Comment: Why not just use an interface?  If `FOO` and `BAR` both implemented `IDoSomething` that just declared a `DoSomething()` method signature, you'd be in business.

Comment: @Sjips Actually they do (CommonRequiredObject) but it wouldn't do him any good as written.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.  What I am trying to avoid is doing all the same tasks that ObjectToUse. is doing, in the if() where the code is executing. More types, mean more common code repeated in the if() structure.  Maybe I could move the logic of the if() into the Base<T> class to return a new object?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Yes, you're right, otherwise `System.Object` would be the common ancestor. What I meant was that Base<string> and Base<byte> have not a common ancestor `Base` or so where code could be shared. You're answer explains it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done.

By utilizing a reference that requires a generic type parameter, you must give it one. You could utilize `dynamic` here so that the type is run-time evaluated, but thats the best you will get.

Even utilizing something like a template method pattern, you would need to specify the generic type argument. If you just want the `DoSomething` method for this, it would need to be promoted to a higher base class (or an interface) so you could hold a reference to *that* type, and call that (non-generic) function.

To your comment, the solution I would take is this; refactor the common code into a template method pattern *within the base class*. Then have the "triggering" function be a non-generic inherited member from a non-generic base class (or interface). Now, you can hold a reference to that type, and invoke the template method to cause the other calls to occur.

```
public void DoAwesomeStuff() //inherited from non-generic parent or interface
{
   LoadContents(FunctionToGetContents());
   DoSomething();
}
```

Then:

```
IDoesAwesomeStuff ObjectToUse = new FOO();
ObjectToUse.DoAwesomeStuff();
```

Comment: OK. So this would move to the parent of base(), likely a new class in my code as the Utilities.CommonRequiredObject has some basic functionality shared in many places. Base<T> : NewBase, and then the common functions moved into NewBase(). Then NewBase ObjectToUse() and call ObjectToUse.DoAwesomeStuff().

Comment: @StevenScott To avoid modifying your (likely commonly used) base class, I would just add it to an interface, since you can multiply inherit those. Modifying the basic functionality would work too. Certainly an "in-between" base class would work as well, though I doubt you need it.

Comment: @StevenScott Your edited comment would work if you don't want to use an interface.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Working to change my code now.  I need a combination of abstract base class to implement some common functions, and define functions to be implemented in the class, and then the interface as you mention.  My problem is that the class still needs some generics, and this is where I am running into my current issue in moving/re-factoring the code.

Comment: @StevenScott That shouldn't be an issue, just have your generic base class implement `IDoesAwesomeStuff`. Perhaps we should go to chat?

Comment: Thanks for the offer to chat.  I have followed what you suggested, and have a basic sample working correctly.  The combination of abstract class/methods for forcing developers to implement certain pieces, combined with the Interface, is probably the best way to go.  Thanks for the direction and help.

Comment: @StevenScott Not a problem. Just ping me or set up a chat room if you have any other questions!